# how to install kurento on debian?

Tags: kurento

I tried that:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:kurento/kurento
apt-get update
apt-get install kurento-media-server
```

and got 404 errors such as:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources                                                         
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages                
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-fr_FR             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-fr
Err http://ubuntu.kurento.org wheezy/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en                
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources                       
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ubuntu.kurento.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-fr_FR             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-fr                
Ign http://ubuntu.kurento.org wheezy/main Translation-fr_FR
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en                
Ign http://ubuntu.kurento.org wheezy/main Translation-fr               
Ign http://ubuntu.kurento.org wheezy/main Translation-en
W: Aucune clÃ© publique n'est disponible pour la/les clÃ©(s) suivante(s)Â :
7638D0442B90D010
W: Aucune clÃ© publique n'est disponible pour la/les clÃ©(s) suivante(s)Â :
7638D0442B90D010
W: Aucune clÃ© publique n'est disponible pour la/les clÃ©(s) suivante(s)Â :
9D6D8F6BC857C906
W: Impossible de rÃ©cupÃ©rer http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Impossible de rÃ©cupÃ©rer http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Impossible de rÃ©cupÃ©rer http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Impossible de rÃ©cupÃ©rer http://ppa.launchpad.net/kurento/kurento/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Impossible de rÃ©cupÃ©rer http://ubuntu.kurento.org/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Impossible de rÃ©cupÃ©rer http://ubuntu.kurento.org/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Any idea how to install it correctly on Debian server ?

Answer (score 1):

Kurento Media Server (KMS) has to be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bits).

In order to install the latest stable Kurento Media Server version (6.1.1) you have to type the following commands, one at a time and in the same order as listed here. When asked for any kind of confirmation, reply affirmatively:

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but Kurento only supports trusty version, there are also packages for utopic but as utopic is going to be deprecated soon they will be deprecated as well.

Additionally, you are adding source repositories and kurento repositories do not provide them, source code should be get from github.

Regards.

Comment: Is there another way to install in Debian?